# MySQL semi-sync long-distance replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication, galera

we're using two datacenters (east and west coast) where same set of applications work in hot-standby mode (one is primary, second is standby) with local MySQL, so when failover occurs, standby side need to start with actual data, formed by primary side. So we use replication and at the moment it's async master-master replication. For some reasons we need to reconsider the general architecture and among others there is the question about replication.

Whether it's possible to create semi-sync replication cluster in the following way: five nodes (2x east, 2x west, 1x central) compose the cluster, but transaction acknowledgment comes after TWO nodes acknowledged it. What I want to achieve in this way: faster processing (since local and not-too-far central nodes will acknowledge faster) with virtually guaranteed three copies of data. Under normal circumstances it should provide better synchnronisation than async replication, while if something wrong - it will be not worse than async.

Whether (a) it makes sense and (b) can be achieved with MySQL?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html

Comment: Use Galera; it does what you need, plus more.  Your "semi-sync" and "async" and "failover" are not the terms to lean for Galera.